# Migration of project permission, Groups & group members

Tags: gerrit

We have `gerrit - 2.14` version from this we are in a process of migrating all projects(Appropriately 350) to another new gerrit instance(`gerrit - 3.5 version`).

Our goal is to migrate only the below items,

1. Git repository.
2. Each gerrit project's permission, attached groups and group members.

We do not need to migrate the gerrit changes into `gerrit - 3.5 instance`.

For the same, I have tried the below.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for p in `ssh -p 29418 admin@old-review.example.com gerrit ls-projects`
 do
  mkdir -p `dirname "$p"`
  git clone --bare "ssh://admin@old-review.example.com:29418/$p.git" "$p.git"

# Create new project in another instance:
  ssh -p 29418 newadmin@new-review.example.com gerrit create-project "$p" 
  cd "$p.git"
  git remote add newgerrit "ssh://newadmin@new-review.example.com:29418/$p.git"
  git push -f --all newgerrit
  git push -f --tags newgerrit
  cd /gerrit/
done
```

With the above script, i could able to migrate git repositories with its history information.

But including `gerrit project permission, attached groups and group members` migrations i need help.

Any leads to handle this in an automated way will be really appreciated.

Comment: Gerrit's properties are not stored in Git itself, but rather outside of it: see https://git.eclipse.org/r/Documentation/config-gerrit.html

Comment: @torek yes -`project.config` and `group` files from each gerrit repository need to be copied. Any feasabile way available?

Comment: I don't know if there's a formal right way to do it, but raw byte-for-byte copying of idle databases usually *works*. Just make sure they're idle and synced first.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should also copy All-Users.git/ All-Projects.git